# How to access class variables in a TList of Metaclass references?

Tags: delphi

I have a class like this:

```pascal
type
  TCipher = class
    private

    public
        function Encrypt(sText: String; Key: TObject): String; virtual; abstract;
        function Decrypt(sText: String; Key: TObject): String; virtual; abstract;
        class var
          sName: String;
          sDisplayName: String;
  end;
  TCipherClass = class of TCipher;
  
  TCaesar = class(TCipher)
    private

    public
        function Encrypt(sText: String; Key: TObject): String; override;
        function Decrypt(sText: String; Key: TObject): String; override;
        class var
          sName: String;
          sDisplayName: String;
  end;

implementation

function TCaesar.Encrypt(sText: String; Key: TObject): String;
begin
  
end;

function TCaesar.Decrypt(sText: String; Key: TObject): String;
begin
  
end;

initialization

  TCipher.sName := 'defaultName';
  TCipher.sDisplayName := 'defaultDipsplay';
  ShowMessage(TCipher.sName + '  ' + TCipher.sDisplayName);
  
  TCaesar.sName := 'caesar';
  TCaesar.sDisplayName := 'Caesar Cipher';
  ShowMessage(TCaesar.sName + '  ' + TCaesar.sDisplayName);

end.
```

Elsewhere, I have a `TList` of the classes like this:

```pascal
var
  lstCiphers: TList<TCipherClass>;
  cipher: TCipherClass;
begin
  lstCiphers := TList<TCipherClass>.Create;
  lstCiphers.AddRange([TCaesar]);

  for cipher in lstCiphers do
    ShowMessage('In list: ' + cipher.ClassName + ' . ' + cipher.sDisplayName);
end;
```

But this returns `defDipsplay` instead of `Caesar Cipher`. I think this is something I'm doing wrong with the list, because when I show it straight from the class it shows fine:

```pascal
ShowMessage(TCipher.ClassName + ' . ' + TCipher.sDisplayName);
ShowMessage(TCaesar.ClassName + ' . ' + TCaesar.sDisplayName);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variables are declared as `class var`, so they are specific to each class that declares them.   You have `class` variables declared in `TCaesar` that have the same names as `class` variables in `TCipher`, but when you try to access those variables at runtime via a `TCipherClass` metaclass reference, the compiler doesn't know which actual class the metaclass refers to, so all it can do at compile-time is generate code to access the `TCipher`-specific variables, not the `TCaesar`-specific variables.

In this situation, I would suggest using `class virtual` methods instead of `class var`s, then each class can `override` the methods to return different values at runtime.

```pascal
type
  TCipher = class
  public
    function Encrypt(sText: String; Key: TObject): String; virtual; abstract;
    function Decrypt(sText: String; Key: TObject): String; virtual; abstract;
    class function CipherName: String; virtual;
    class function DisplayName: String; virtual;
  end;
  TCipherClass = class of TCipher;
  
  TCaesar = class(TCipher)
  public
    function Encrypt(sText: String; Key: TObject): String; override;
    function Decrypt(sText: String; Key: TObject): String; override;
    class function CipherName: String; override;
    class function DisplayName: String; override;
  end;

implementation

function TCaesar.Encrypt(sText: String; Key: TObject): String;
begin
  ...  
end;

function TCaesar.Decrypt(sText: String; Key: TObject): String;
begin
  ...  
end;

class function TCipher.CipherName: String; 
begin
  Result := 'defaultName';
end;

class function TCipher.DisplayName: String;
begin
  Result := 'defaultDipsplay';
end;

class function TCaesar.CipherName: String;
begin
  Result := 'caesar';
end;

class function TCaesar.DisplayName: String;
begin
  Result := 'Caesar Cipher';
end;

initialization
  ShowMessage(TCipher.CipherName + '  ' + TCipher.DisplayName);
  ShowMessage(TCaesar.CipherName + '  ' + TCaesar.DisplayName);

end.
```

```pascal
var
  lstCiphers: TList<TCipherClass>;
  cipher: TCipherClass;
begin
  lstCiphers := TList<TCipherClass>.Create;
  lstCiphers.Add(TCaesar);

  for cipher in lstCiphers do
    ShowMessage('In list: ' + cipher.ClassName + ' . ' + cipher.CipherName + '.' + cipher.DisplayName);
end;
```

Comment: This is a better solution.  I was going to expand my answer with some cleaner alternatives a bit later today but you beat me to it!  +1

Answer (score 1):

You've redeclared `sName` and `sDisplayName` in `TCaesar` so these are hiding the same-named variables in the ancestor `TCipher` class.  Just remove that declaration and you get the behaviour you expect.

```
  TCaesar = class(TCipher)
    private

    public
        function Encrypt(sText: String; Key: TObject): String; override;
        function Decrypt(sText: String; Key: TObject): String; override;            
  end;
```

The `sName` and `sDisplayName` fields will still be members of `TCaesar` here because they will be inherited from `TCipher`.  If you declare new variables with the same name in a descendent class then they will hide the ancestor variables when referenced directly via a reference of the descendent type.  When using a variable that treats the object as an ancestor, however, you will read and write to the ancestor's fields instead.